# Tough SQL query - Records for me since I the last time I sent them a message

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a message table with the following fields

```
id integer auto-incrementing field
createdate datetime
msg_to integer
msg_from integer
msg
```

msg_to and msg_from store the user ids.  How would I write a SQL query that retrieves all records for me (msg_to=1) since I sent them a message(msg_from=1)?  The objective is to retrieve all new message records.  Is this possible in SQL or will I need to do logic in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a.*
from `table` a
inner join (
    /* last message to them */
    select msg_to, max(createdate) as lastsent
    from `table`
    where msg_from = @MyID
    group by msg_to
) b on a.msg_from = b.msg_to and a.createdate > b.lastsent
where a.msg_to = @MyID
```